# How to make Firefox remember HTTP password

Tags: windows, firefox, passwords

I am using Firefox 46.0.1 on Windows 7. [From what I read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/passwords) it can store HTTP authentication credentials. However, my installation won't.

E.g. this [test page](http://browserspy.dk/password.php) asks for HTTP Basic Authentication credentials.

[[image: Firefox password dialog]]

But after restarting the browser it will ask again. And there is no "Save password" check box or the like. I played around with *about:config* but got nowhere.

Comment: [Make Firefox remember usernames and passwords](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import#w_make-firefox-remember-usernames-and-passwords)?

Comment: [Usernames and passwords are not saved](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/usernames-and-passwords-are-not-saved#w_remember-password-prompt-is-not-displayed)

Comment: You can use the Saved Passwords Editor extension for web sites where Firefox doesn't offer to save the Username /Password.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60265/

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that storing passwords entered into HTML forms works fine, i.e. I see the "Remember Password" prompt

Comment: The Saved Passwords Editor add-on does the trick, thanks! Maybe I can still find out what's wrong with my installation.

Comment: Answer added :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works again since updating to Firefox 47, i.e. the "Would you like Firefox to remember this login?" is displayed for HTTP passwords and works as expected.

Recommending David's solution if updating is not possible or a subsequent release shows the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### There is no "Save password" check box or the like.

> I played around with about:config but got nowhere.

You can use the [Saved Passwords Editor](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60265) extension for web sites where Firefox doesn't offer to save the Username /Password:

> **About this Add-on**
>
> This extension allows you to enter data into the
>   Password Manager database instead of relying on Firefox, Thunderbird,
>   SeaMonkey, etc., to do it, as well as making changes to existing
>   entries. For web forms, the typical usage is as follows:
>
> - Navigate to the page containing the login form.
> - Right-click on one of its fields and select from among "Save login info" (to create a new entry), "Edit login info", and "Delete
>     login info".
> - If another popup appears, select the username for the entry you want to operate on.
> - If adding a new entry, everything except the username and password should be filled in automatically. Fill in anything that is
>     missing or incorrect.
> - If adding or editing an entry, reload the page or return later. If the form doesn't get autofilled, most likely the page is asking the
>     browser not to autofill it by declaring autocomplete="off". Try
>     clicking twice on the username field and selecting from the dropdown
>     list. There is a video demonstrating this workaround.
>
> This add-on also adds commands to the Password Manager window, which
>   it makes accessible through Tools > Saved Passwords as well as a
>   toolbar button.

Source [Saved Passwords Editor](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60265)

Answer (score 0):

This maybe late answer but my solution is very simple.
**If you're using a 64-bit Windows just update Firefox to the latest 64-bit version**.
This bug has been fixed in 64-bit version. Go to this [Mozilla Firefox download page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/?q=English%20(US)) and downloaded and follow the prompts to install the 64-bit version of Firefox.